Camel route diagram in Hawtio does not present multicast as parallel branches

I have this simple Camel route with multicast:

 
- route:
    id: route-f758
    trace: true
    from:
      id: from-e730
      uri: direct
      parameters:
        name: example
      steps:
        - multicast:
            id: multicast-3ba3
            parallelProcessing: true
            steps:
              - log:
                  id: log-e33fx
                  message: s1 ${body}
              - log:
                  id: log-15c2fx
                  message: s2 ${body} 



In Hawtio tree on the left side this route is presented correctly



But in route diagram this route is presented as a sequence of calls:


Note that choice alternatives are presented correctly.
Is there any setting or something? (e.g. does Camel internally optimize route to sequence?)
I use camel 4.6.0 and hawtio (hawtio-springboot) 4.0.0

It's probably a display bug in Hawtio. Hawtio Camel plugin is not yet aware of the parallelProcessing option.
